# Derive the maximum value formula for n digit in base x i.e M= x^n-1

Tags: math

For n binary digits with base x, the maximum value will be:

```
x^(n-1) + x^(n-2) + ... + x^1 + x^0
```

By using geometric progression,
r=1/x
Using formula for sum of n finite numbers i get:

```
(x^n - 1) / (x - 1).
```

But my answer should have been x^n - 1.(formula: M= x^n - 1)

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the sum of the geometric series x<sup>0</sup> + x<sup>1</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> + ... + x<sup>n-1</sup> is indeed (x<sup>n</sup> - 1) / (x - 1). For example, if we pick x = 10 (base 10) and n = 3 (a three-digit base 10 number), we get back

> 1 + 10 + 100 = (1000 - 1) / 9 = 999 / 9 = 111.

However, the largest three-digit number is 999. And by looking at the above sum, you might get a sense of why we're off by a factor of 9. When writing out numbers in base 10, we'd maximize our number by having each digit be 9, not 1. And more generally, in base x, we'd maximize our value by having each digit be x - 1. That means that the maximum value is

> (x - 1)(x<sup>0</sup> + x<sup>1</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> + ... + x<sup>n-1</sup>) = (x - 1)(x<sup>n</sup> - 1)/(x - 1) = x<sup>n</sup> - 1.

Here's another, easier way to see this. What is the *smallest* number you can make with n+1 digits? That would be x<sup>n</sup>. Since that's the smallest (n+1)-digit number, the *largest* n-digit number must be that minus one, giving x<sup>n</sup> - 1 without needing to discuss geometric series.

Comment: The explanation is very clear, and the last paragraph is awesome.